# Mocking Browser Environment in a Typescript Test

Tags: typescript, testing

I have a set of typescript files that are being compiled and running a browser window.

I'd then like to write a set of tests in Typescript that would run in the Node environment, which would require mocking out any window APIs.

I can't find a clean way to do this with Typescript, often ending up with

> Cannot find name 'location'.

I tried to define the location, but still had no joy as I declaring the interface and not an instance (which I'd like to stub in each test).

> 'location' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
>
> 6   if (location.origin ===

Any ideas of how this could / should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.location` in your code instead of just `location`.  Typescript includes a library (dom) that has a type `Window` that the `window` object implements.

Small excerpt from the lib.dom.d.ts file:

```
interface Window extends EventTarget, WindowTimers, WindowSessionStorage, WindowLocalStorage, WindowConsole, GlobalEventHandlers, IDBEnvironment, WindowBase64, GlobalFetch {
...
readonly location: Location;
...
}
```

After that, I assume you can just mock the `window` object.